# Is it better to eval dynamically-generated code or store it in a temp file and include it?

Tags: php

Sometimes I need to create PHP code for formatting arrays on the fly. one way to do this is to use `eval`. but I think of writing the generated code to a PHP file and then include it. This has many advantages to `eval`, one of them is caching of generated code. But I haven't seen such a practice in other code. I don't know if there's any problem regarding security or other things with this?

This is an example:

```
<?php

$code = '<? foreach($rows as $row) {$row["insertion"] = format($row["insertion"]);} ?>'
file_put_contents('formatter.php', $code);
include('formatter.php');

?>
```

I just want to know is it good to create a PHP file on the fly and then include it?

Or is it better to just go ahead and `eval()` the code directly, with no stored history?

Comment: Please just tell us what you are trying to achieve and I will find a proper solution for you. What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "I just want to know is it good to create php file on the fly and then include it????" No! See my comment above.

Comment: My question is very general and clear!  is it good to create php file on the fly and then include it????

Comment: What is `caching of generated code`? This, looks like madness to me. It's the same thing right?

Comment: Is it good to create a file and include it? No, no it is not, write proper code to do what you want.

Comment: This is less efficient than eval, since you're hitting the file system to save then load that temporary file. But regardless of efficiency, eval() and this simulation of eval() are pretty much universally a bad idea.

Comment: "My question is very general and clear!" If I would answer you like I did. I.e. by saying **no!** (which would answer your question) you still haven't a solution that works. So although your question is clear it probably isn't the right question.

Comment: Thancks Marc B, at lease one good comment. Actually in a real program so many files are loaded, so I don't think the filesystem make my code slow. One other way to it is to use __get which induce much more load!

Comment: My question is general. I don't have any problem. I just want to know if it's good to generate php file or not?

Comment: To all the downvoters, this is a very clear and thought out question. Why all the hate? Are you in some sort of anti-`eval()` frenzy?

Comment: why don't you just have the PHP code right there in your .php file instead of including it?

Comment: @Blaine Just because you have not run across use cases for this doesn't mean there aren't any certifiably good ones. And why should Ali have to explain his methods? He just asked a simple question. There's no need for all this -4 downvotes, gosh.

Comment: Ali - First off, you are asking for feedback. If that feedback isn't to your liking, it doesn't mean it "isn't good" -- your comment "at lease one good comment" is pretty disrespectful. PeeHaa IS giving you "good" comments, you just don't want to hear what he is telling you. @Theodore R. Smith -- I am ALWAYS in an anti-eval frenzy. There is never, never, never a reason to use eval. Ever. Yes, I said it - ever.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith See PeeHaa's initial comment

Comment: @Chris everyone just started attacking him and downvoting like crazy. The underlying and usually overt impression I get from reading the above responses is that most people inherently judge him as inferior, that he must not know what he's doing since he's asking this question, and immediately downvote. Then he starts defending himself and you guys call him rude ;o

Comment: @Chris, You could say you'r anti eval! If you'r anti it so there is nothing to discuss with you because I want to use it! ;)

Comment: @Chris You said, "I am ALWAYS in an anti-eval frenzy. There is never, never, never a reason to use eval. Ever. Yes, I said it - ever." There are valid use cases out there (such as with templating engines) where either evaluating code or saving it and including it (largely the same thing, but better) really helps. If you're close-minded to this, fine, but just don't downvote people.

Comment: Is that wise, Ali? To reject all feedback from those who don't agree with your pre-formed ideas? Why seek feedback? Theodore, I didn't downvote anyone, and I urge you (and Ali) to be a little more rational.

Comment: END IT! END THE DISCUSSION, BOTH SIDES!!! Next person who posts after this is the clear aggressor, so be sure to delete your posts if any. Both sides are well-documented, let's jsut end it in a "We'll agree to disagree" state.

Comment: This *is* a constructive question! It's just that haters turned it into a trollfest and then voted to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to create code dynamically, it is always more efficient and usually more secure to dump the output into a file and then include it. Then you only have to do this once per piece of code *and* it allows for opcodes caching (via APC and the like) and more efficient preprocessing by the Zend Core engine.  ANother benefit is that you can debug included files, while debugging `eval()`ed statements is rarely supported.

The reason it is more secure to store it into a file is that then you have a record of what was run; with `eval()`, it's more or less a black box and you have no idea what's been executing.  Additionally, you should be able to lock down the writes folder to where only a certain app can write to it.  If you separate your dynamic array creation logic from your main app, and then include the file via your main app itself, this will undoubtedly increase security and performance, assuming you've made the temp files read-only to Apache and writeable only by the PHP app (doable via cron, among other methods).

There's possibly a better solution for what you're doing (like memcache or APC fetch/store) but I have run into similar circumstances that largely benefited from the including stuff (for instance, tweaking smarty templates to be included rather than eval'd worked amazingly).

Comment: Why would it be more secure???

Comment: Ali, people (particularly PHP developers) tend to have knee-jerk reactions where they downvote anything that goes against the normative thought.  The normative thought in this case is that what you are doing is Wrong (tm) and that alternatives to `eval()` will be equally wrong.

Comment: When I jump out of a plane without a parachute it is more safe because I know I am jumping without a parachute. Which is way more safe the jumping out of a plane and only while jumping I realize my chute doesn't work. I have news for you. In both situations it probably won't end well.

Comment: Hey @PeeHaa, you do realize that storing dynamic code is not inherently unsafe, right?  Ali isn't talking about evaluating code based on direct user inputs or anything. He's asking if it's better for **concise, defined, and purposeful** dynamic code to be included or evaluated. This isn't really inherently unsafe, bro.

Comment: Code generation is a very common practice in other languages. I don't think it's bad. sometime a generated code can do things much faster!

Comment: Exactly, my code is just internal, not from user input!

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to use the generated code once, and only once, then you're better off using eval.

However, I question the practice here. Your example code is either too trivial to adequately justify the need for this pattern, OR you are over-complicating what could be basic procedural code and a closure or something.

General guidelines:

- If you are generating **and then calling* dynamic code in a production environment, you might be approaching your problem incorrectly
- `eval` is regarded as bad practice in 99.999% of all circumstances
- Generated code that will never be called again should be `eval`ed
- Generated code that will (or very likely will) be called in the future should be cached either to file or database

Comment: This is a good answer! instead of debating! ;)

Comment: I have got accustomed with -1s! here if people don't like something start voting down regardless of what it is! it's not important!